# webcam motion tracking with Python

Tags: python, motion-detection

Is there a simple way to track the motions of a single entity in a webcam feed? For example, I imagine a "hello world" app with an index finger used as mouse pointer.

I realize there's still a lot of basic research in this area, so it might be too early to expect an easy to use, generic abstraction.

For the sake of completeness, I've seen some related but lower-level (and non-Python) projects being mentioned, including [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), [WiimoteLib](http://www.codeplex.com/WiimoteLib) and [an article on motion detection algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx).

Comment: I am doubting that you'll find anything simple and out of the box, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface. I'm not sure how hard it would be to do arbitrary motion tracking, but it was fairly simple to implement face tracking.

Comment: +1 OpenCV would be the most mature solution to use from Python afaik.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! I might have found a "hello world" app too: http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2008/01/tracking-laser-pointer-with-python-and.html - will investigate.